# Issue of IC 7486 and IC 74LS86 Exclusive Or Gate in Proteus,

Tags: integrated-circuit, proteus

Why does IC 7486 Exclusive OR gate is giving and error in PROTEUS Simulation. Error is Simulation Failed due to partition analysis error.
But when IC 74LS86 is implemented it works. Truth Table of Exclusive OR gate is then verified.
What is the difference between IC 7486 an IC 74LS86.
Why IC 74LS86 is working properly but IC 7486 is giving an error?

Answer (score 2):

When you choose 7486, does the preview say "no simulator model"? If so then you will get the error you described because the version of Proteus you are using doesn't have a Spice model for that part.

[image]

Comment: No it's giving an error "Simulation Error due to partition analysis error."